# Trying to add IPv6 route returns an RTNETLINK answers error

Tags: routing, centos5, ipv6

On CentOS 5.10 I'm trying to add static IPv6 route via external GW (6::a0c:34a) as follows:

```
ip -6 route add 12::/64 via 6::a0c:34a dev eth1
```

The above returns a **RTNETLINK answers: Invalid** argument error.

Now if I try the same but change the GW addr to **2006::a0c:34a**

```
ip -6 route add 12::/64 via 2006::a0c:34a dev eth1
```

everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you get IANA to delegate that address space to you? :-)  If they didn't: please use real addresses from either your ISP, PI addresses or ULA addresses. There is no reason to hijack unused address space in IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a route whose gateway is an invalid IP address. If you try, you receive the `Invalid argument` error.

(But you *can* add routes *to* invalid IP address ranges. This is to support bogon handling, blackholing, and various other oddball scenarios that you should not normally have to deal with.)

To resolve this problem, renumber your network so that all hosts have valid IPv6 addresses.